# Add validations to a dynamic object in VUE js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to add a "Required" validation to a dynamic object in VUE(I'm knew in VUE). I don't know what will be the object keys until the user will fill a certain input field.

After that I want to implement a span with error to present the user with a custom error.

Object fields presented here with v-for:

```
  <div v-for="(param, key, index) in params" :key="key">
    <label class="inputLabel" :for="key">Please fill in {{ key }} param</label> <span class="redStar">*</span>
    <input v-model="params[key]" :id="key">
    <span v-if="submitted && !$v.params[key].required" class="invalid-feedback">It's a required field, please fill it</span>
  </div>
```

I tried this way:

```
computed:{
    params() {

      if (this.jsonS.hasOwnProperty(this.tDetails.platform)) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.jsonS[this.tDetails.platform])) {
          this.params[key] = value;
        }
      }
      return this.params;
    },
    addRequiredValidation(){
        //Here I need somehow to add validations to params object.
      }
    },
```

Validations as follows:

```
  validations() {
    return {
       // integrationParams: this.addRequiredValidation,
      tDetails: {
        param1: { required, minLength: minLength(3) },
        param2: { required, minLength: minLength(3) },
        param3: { required, minLength: minLength(3) },
        param4: { required, minLength: minLength(2) },
        param5: { required, minLength: minLength(2) }
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: ```this.params[key] = { required }``` here required is not defined. The computed variable is not returning anything, so it would be undefined. 
Please clean your code to correct and to be understood by other if you want other to help fast :)

Comment: That's what I tried to do, I know it's not working. That's why I came here for help. 
I can't figure out how to add the { Required } value here.

Comment: Params is a dynamic object as I mentioned, so I can't add validations statically like I did for tDetails for example, that's my issue

Comment: I edited the code, tried to make it more simple